# How do I control the order of ExpandableObject properties in the winforms property grid?

Tags: .net, winforms, propertygrid

I have classes like:

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Inner
{
   public string Before{get;set}
   public string After(get;set}
}

public class Outer
{
    public Inner Inner {get;set}
}

myPropertygrid.SelectedObject = new Outer();
```

I wish the properties of “inner” to be displayed as “Before”, “After”, the property grid seems to put them in alphabetically order and hence display them as “After”, “Before”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not like this solution but it seems to work:

Create a sub class of “PropertyDescriptorCollection” with all “Sort” methods override just to return “this”.  So whenever the property grid calls sort to change the order of the properties, nothing happens.

Create a subclass of “ExpandableObjectConverter” that have the “GetProperties” method overridden to return an instance of  “NoneSortingPropertyDescriptorCollection” with the properties in the correct order.

Use the [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyExpandableObjectConverter))] to get your subclass of ExpandableObjectConverter used.

```
public class NoneSortingPropertyDescriptorCollection : PropertyDescriptorCollection
{
    public NoneSortingPropertyDescriptorCollection(PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors)
        : base(propertyDescriptors)
    {
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection Sort()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection Sort(string[] names)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection Sort(string[] names, System.Collections.IComparer comparer)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection Sort(System.Collections.IComparer comparer)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class MyExpandableObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection d = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);

        List<PropertyDescriptor> props = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        props.Add(d.Find("Before", false));
        props.Add(d.Find("After", false));

        NoneSortingPropertyDescriptorCollection m = new NoneSortingPropertyDescriptorCollection(props.ToArray());
        return m;
    }
}

[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyExpandableObjectConverter))]      
public class Inner      
{         
   public string Before{get;set}        
   public string After(get;set}      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *PropertyGrid.PropertySort* property to alter the ordering of the properties. Possible values are as follow...

```
NoSort
Alphabetical
Categorized
CategorizedAlphabetical
```

I would suggest the *NoSort* as the appropriate value for you.

Comment: That would imply overriding the behavior too, if you can inherit from that attribute.

Comment: Sorry, this effects the order of ALL properties in the property grid, I only wish to control the order of the properties on the "inner object" and let the user control the order of the other properites as normal.

Comment: Not possible, you can only alter the ordering on all the properties shown.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question but this solution is simpler than the accepted one:

```
public class MyExpandableObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Inner), attributes).Sort(new[] { "Before", "After" });
    }
}

[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(MyExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Inner
{
    public string Before { get; set; }
    public string After { get; set; }
}
```